# fail to pull from remote git repo

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I checkout to `develop` branch, and run `git pull`, I got error of `fatal: 'develop' does not appear to be a git repository`. Instead, I have to do `git pull origin develop`. Why is that so? Something is wrong with my git setup?

Comment: I fail to see a question here

Comment: @hd1, updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not you have configured the default remote branch, the syntax of [`git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) is:

- false in your question: `git pull [<options>] [<repository> [<refspec>…​]]`
  That would be

  ```
  git pull origin develop
  NOT: git pull develop
  ```

The first argument is the name of the remote repository, and, as the error message indicated, "`develop`" is *not* a remote repository. `origin` is.

- false in [hd1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783412/hd1)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57423299/6309): `git pull -u` does not exists.

  ```
  git push -u origin develop
  ```

That last command would have establish a link between the local branch develop and the remote tracking branch origin/develop.

In your case, since you want to pull and not push:

```
git fetch
git checkout --track origin/dev
```

If the local branch `develop` already exists, see "[Make an existing Git branch track a remote branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2286030/6309)":

```
git branch -u origin/develop develop
git checkout develop
git pull
```

Comment: this `git branch -u origin/develop develop` fixed my issue, but I have no clue when did I broke this

Answer (score 1):

You've not configured a default remote for the branch. Do so using `git pull origin -u develop`.